# java language tool library, cannot find dependency

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol, languagetool

I am using [this](http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api) example code to use the API. I don't want to use maven so I downloaded the jar files from [here](https://languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-3.5.zip), and included the Jar files in org and lib to the build path, then tried to run the example code. I got this error:

```
Error:(15, 56) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BritishEnglish
  location: class draft
Error:(3, 34) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BritishEnglish
  location: package org.languagetool.language
```

here is my code

```
import org.languagetool.JLanguageTool;
import org.languagetool.language.BritishEnglish;
import org.languagetool.rules.RuleMatch;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

public class draft {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(new BritishEnglish());
        // comment in to use statistical ngram data:
        //langTool.activateLanguageModelRules(new File("/data/google-ngram-data"));
        List<RuleMatch> matches = langTool.check("A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker's Guide tot he Galaxy");
        for (RuleMatch match : matches) {
            System.out.println("Potential error at characters " +
                    match.getFromPos() + "-" + match.getToPos() + ": " +
                    match.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Suggested correction(s): " +
                    match.getSuggestedReplacements());
        }
    }
}
```

I found this answer online, but I don't understand it.

" BritishEnglish is in the "org" directory and not in the JARs, but you can put in a JAR like this: "zip -r languages.jar org/", then add languages.jar to your classpath like the other JARs. "

Comment: This isn't so much a code problem as it is a build / execution one. We need to see your CLASSPATH and also how you are invoking your draft class.

Comment: @jameson I made an edit, please check it, maybe u can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language implementations themselves are packed into separate jars, apparently. The one you need is in language-en.jar:

https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/languagetool/language-en/3.5/language-en-3.5.jar

You can see it here:

```
jameson@spinach:~$ jar -tf language-en-3.5.jar | grep BritishEnglish
org/languagetool/language/BritishEnglish.class
```

Try downloading and it and adding it to your classpath. Also be sure to do the items in the doc: http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api#toc4 . I don't recommend repacking a dependency jar, that's kludgy. I also do recommend using maven instead.